# line 42: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, syntax

I'm attempting to make a simply security log-in that prompts the user to input a name and then if said name matches one of the if statements, it proceeds to have them enter a password followed by an `su` log in. it kicks back with

> line 42: syntax error: unexpected end of file

after entering the data into the first user input prompt for the name.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

clear

read -p "Please enter your name:" i

if [ "$i" = "Tyler" ]
then
   read -p "Hello Tyler. Please enter you password now:" b

   if [ "$b" = "1234567890" ]
   then
      echo "You really are Tyler!! Prove it again!!"
      su

   else
      echo "WRONG ANSWER!!"

      if [ "$i" = "LouRae" ]
      then
         read -p "Hey there beautiful. Please enter you password now:" b

         if [ "$b" = "123456789" ]
         then
            echo "You really are LouRae!! Prove it again!!"
            su
         else
            echo "WRONG ANSWER!!!"

            if [ "$i" = "Emma" ]
            then
               read -p "Hello Emma. Please enter you password now:" b

               if [ "$b" = "12345678" ]
               then
                  echo "You really are Emma!! Prove it again!!"
                  su
               else
                  echo "WRONG ANSWER!!!"

               fi
```

Comment: It's pretty hard to understand the code like this. Could you please upload a text file with the script or take a screenshot to make it easier to review?

Comment: With this code you need to close all your `if` statements.  So, instead of 1 `fi` at the end, you need a total of 6 `fi`'s all in a row to close them all out.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Please don't add "answered", "solved", etc. to the title. Mark the answer as accepted, instead, by clicking on the tick next to it. See http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to end every `if` statement with `fi`, like

```
if [ "$i" = "Tyler" ]
    then
        read -p "Hello Tyler. Please enter you password now:" b         

            if [ "$b" = "1234567890" ]
                    then
                        echo "You really are Tyler!! Prove it again!!"
                        su

            else
                echo "WRONG ANSWER!!"
            fi
fi
```

Comment: I went through and corrected and the script flows perfectly!! Thank you for the quickness of your response. i will post the updated script in a new answer.

Comment: Don't think down of my first post on here.  How exactly do I mark this as answered? Thanks for the heads up brother. I'll be sure to on my next post.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED SCRIPT (WORKING)

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

read -p "Please enter your name:" i

if [ "$i" = "Tyler" ]
    then
        read -p "Hello Tyler. Please enter you password now:" b         

            if [ "$b" = "1234567890" ]
                    then
                        echo "You really are Tyler!! Prove it again!!"
                        su

            else
                echo "WRONG ANSWER!!"
        fi
fi

if [ "$i" = "LouRae" ]
    then 
        read -p "Hey there beautiful. Please enter you password now:" b

            if [ "$b" = "123456789" ]
                    then
                        echo "You really are LouRae!! Prove it again!!"
                        su
            else
                        echo "WRONG ANSWER!!!"
        fi
fi

if [ "$i" = "Emma" ]
    then
        read -p "Hello Emma. Please enter you password now:" b

            if [ "$b" = "12345678" ]
                    then
                        echo "You really are Emma!! Prove it again!!"
                        su
            else
                        echo "WRONG ANSWER!!!"
        fi
fi
```